# Generate Swimlane Diagram Automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flowchart

We used to draw swimlane diagram using popular editors, such as Visio. Is there any software or plugin, in eclipse, which generates swimlane diagram automatically?

Like when we run our application, the software must automatically track the control flow and generate corresponding swimlane diagrams?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

http://superuser.com/questions/865528/open-source-software-for-generating-swimlane-graphics